# android read file and upload

Tags: android, upload

I have a code:

```
 File myFile = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/1.jpg");
            FileInputStream fin = null;

                // create FileInputStream object
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                byte fileContent[] = new byte[(int)myFile.length()];

                // Reads up to certain bytes of data from this input stream into an array of bytes.
                try {
                    fin.read(fileContent);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                //create string from byte array
                String s = new String(fileContent);


        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, "image/jpeg", s);
```

But when I go with my browser, I see a corrupt JPEG file. what am I doing wrong? I want a user when enters some address to see 1.jpg file

Edit: Changed code to:

```
  File myFile = new File("/sdcard/Pictures/MyCameraApp/1.jpg");
            FileInputStream fin = null;

                // create FileInputStream object
                try {
                    fin = new FileInputStream(myFile);
                } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                byte[] b = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                try {
                    while ((bytesRead = fin.read(b)) != -1) {
                       bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                byte[] fileContent = bos.toByteArray();

                //create string from byte array
                String s = new String(fileContent);


        return new NanoHTTPD.Response(HTTP_OK, "image/jpg", s);
```

Still Doesn't work..... When I enter page, I get corrupt jpg file, (doesn't work either if I write image/jpeg instead image/jpg, or text/html, save the text as jpg file. works perfecly for text :\

Answer (score 2):

### How to Read Bytes From a File in Android

The code is only reading the beginning of your file. That is why the *bytes* that arrive on the server appear as a corrupt image file.

Try these code modifications:

```
fin = new FileInputStream(myFile);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] b = new byte[1024];
while ((int bytesRead = fin.read(b)) != -1) {
   bos.write(b, 0, bytesRead);
}
byte[] fileContent = bos.toByteArray();
```

Of course, you'll have to wrap in all of the appropriate `Exception` handlers.

Comment: I'm sure you are close to a solution. Check two things: a) Verify that the file "1.jpg" is a valid image file by browsing to it on your sdcard. And, b) I see you are converting `fileContent` into a `String` like this: `String s = new String(fileContent);`. I hope that is old code. **DO NOT** send the `String` "s" to the internet! That would be another problem. You must send the `byte[]` array in your upload function.

Comment: Here is what you appear to be trying to do: a) Read `FileInputStream` into a `ByteArrayOutputStream`. b) read `ByteArrayOutputStream` into a `byte[]` array (_this could fill all your memory!_), c) convert `byte[]` array into a `String` (_this will 100% guaranteed lose data and corrupt your .jpg_), and d) upload the `String`. It will work to send the `byte[]` array instead of the `String`, but you may also need to pipe your `FileInputStream` directly to an `OutputStream` connected to your Internet connection.

Answer (score -1):

this solution isn't mine but can be useful, mimics a upload form you can found the source [here](http://reecon.wordpress.com/2010/04/25/uploading-files-to-http-server-using-post-android-sdk/)

```
class Utils {
    public static void upload(String filePath, String urlServer) {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        DataOutputStream outputStream = null;
        DataInputStream inputStream = null;

        String lineEnd = "\r\n";
        String twoHyphens = "--";
        String boundary =  "*****";

        int bytesRead, bytesAvailable, bufferSize;
        byte[] buffer;
        int maxBufferSize = 1*1024*1024;

        try  {
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(pathToOurFile) );

            URL url = new URL(urlServer);
            connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // Allow Inputs & Outputs
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setUseCaches(false);

            // Enable POST method
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

            connection.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
            connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary="+boundary);

            outputStream = new DataOutputStream( connection.getOutputStream() );
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"uploadedfile\";filename=\"" + pathToOurFile +"\"" + lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);

            bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
            bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
            buffer = new byte[bufferSize];

            // Read file
            bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);

            while (bytesRead > 0) {
                outputStream.write(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
                bytesAvailable = fileInputStream.available();
                bufferSize = Math.min(bytesAvailable, maxBufferSize);
                bytesRead = fileInputStream.read(buffer, 0, bufferSize);
            }

            outputStream.writeBytes(lineEnd);
            outputStream.writeBytes(twoHyphens + boundary + twoHyphens + lineEnd);

            // Responses from the server (code and message)
            serverResponseCode = connection.getResponseCode();
            serverResponseMessage = connection.getResponseMessage();

            fileInputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            //Exception handling
        }
    }
}
```

reception code

```
<?php
    $target_path  = "./";
    $target_path = $target_path . basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']);
    if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploadedfile']['tmp_name'], $target_path)) {
        echo "The file ".  basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded";
    } else{
        echo "There was an error uploading the file, please try again!";
    }
?>
```